# Sql for finding the distance between using latitude and longitude returns wrong distance

Tags: php, mysql, location, latitude-longitude

i need to get the distance between location of the latitude and longitude, 
mysql query works without error but it returns the wrong distance value

When i enter the same latitude and longitude as in the database it gives the distance as "2590.4238273460855" instead of zero, i dont known whats wrong in this

mysql query is as given below
here latitude and longitude are my table column name

```
$sql = "SELECT id,(3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( $latitude - latitude) *  pi()/180 / 2), 2) +COS( $latitude * pi()/180) * COS(latitude * pi()/180) * POWER(SIN(( $longitude - longitude ) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) ))) as distance  
from table_name ORDER BY distance limit 100";
```

can anyone help me please..

Comment: When I run this query, I get a number very close to zero (not exactly zero because of imprecision in converting to radians). Can you also show the code where you set up the variables and execute the query?

Comment: Please show us the values of $lat, $lng, lat, lng that cause the 2590...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an error in your Haversine formula. Haversine formula is:

> Haversine_distance=   r * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(a))

where

> a = POW(SIN(latDiff / 2), 2) + COS(lat1) * COS(lat2) * POW(SIN(LonDiff / 2),
>   2)

Therefore, to correct your code change your query to:

```
"SELECT id,(3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT( POWER(SIN(( $latitude - latitude) / 2), 2) +COS( $latitude) * COS(latitude) * POWER(SIN(( $longitude - longitude ) / 2), 2) ))) as distance from table_name ORDER BY distance limit 100";
```

Comment: when i executed this query i get an sql error   - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"' at line 1

Comment: My query is the same as your query, I just removed all the instances of *  pi()/180 in your query. So in theory it should not fail. Try removing them from your own query and let me know if that works.

Comment: your code is correct and its my mistake of giving the wrong input, am sorry, thanks for sharing your time

Comment: I hope my answer is the correct one and it helped you solve the problem.